# geolocation.getCurrentPosition issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I have an issue regarding geolocation.getCurrentPosition()

I have the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#find_pickupStoresNearMe_button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formAction = $(this).parents('form').attr('action');
    $('#locationForSearch').val('');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        console.log(position);
        ACC.pickupinstore.locationSearchSubmit('', formAction, position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("An error occurred... The error code and message are: " + error.code + "/" + error.message);
    });
});
```

The problem is that the functions jumps straight into the function(error) because the position is undefined.I have the same code in a different folder for a different store and the html structure is the same and it works fine retrieving the City I request in a search input.

HTML code:

```
<form id="command" name="pickupInStoreForm" class="searchPOSForm clearfix" action="/store/store-pickup/pointOfServices"
    method="POST">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="control-group left">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="locationQuery" id="locationForSearch" class="left" placeholder="Adauga Oras">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="" id="pickupstore_search_button">Gaseste magazin</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="" id="find_pickupStoresNearMe_button">Localizeaza pozitia pe harta</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
```

I am new to javascript and jQuery, sorry if the question is poorly stated or if extra info is needed, let me know. Any help on where whould I look for the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps you've permanently "blocked" position for a particular site? (getCurrentPosition only works with https sites, you know that much, right?)

Comment: whats the error code/message you are getting.

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel it's just the function(error) popping up, it skips the first function called, there is no syntax error in the console.

Comment: @JaromandaX it's not the case, it works in a different shop that has the same code, and I have no syntax errors

Comment: Also, there is no lock symbol there

Comment: I don't know what "shop" refers to, but I assume you know what you are doing, and that each shop is not in it's own (sub)domain

Comment: try to log `error` from error callback and post in the question so that we can have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if these works.

```
$(function($) {
    $('#pickupstore_search_button').on('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
        console.log(pos)
      }, (err) => {
         console.error(err)
      });
    });
});
```

Otherwise, click on lock symbol in before URL( before https), go to the site settings and set Location to ask default or allow.

[image]

Maybe

[image]

Comment: Same issue, I put breakpoints in the console and after it reaches getCurrentPosition, it jumps out of the function (it does not console log anything, neither pos, nor err)

Comment: Did you try to click on the lock symbol?

Comment: I don't see a lock symbol before the URL

Comment: thanks, it did the job, the lock symbol was the problem